# Wild Web Developer - Angular Language Service is not yet enabled for project .../tsconfig.json

Tags: angular, eclipse, wildwebdeveloper, angular-language-service

I'm trying to import an Angular project into Eclipse / Wild Web Developer. I just imported the Angular app root folder.

In the error log I see the following message:

> `Language Service is not yet enabled for project /PATH/TO/tsconfig.json`

If I trust the following, it should be enabled.

[image: eclipse activated language server]

How can I enable the language service?

Comment: It looks like WWD error, see https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/783